# Delay Fragment loading on Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am developing an Android app in android studio 4.0.1 with a min sdk 21.

I am using java as my preferred language.

I have a main activity which is the parent for three fragments.
first fragment: login,
second fragment: register,
third fragment: home

I am trying to use the conditional navigation in main activity to load fragment based on login condition. If user already logged in , go to home screen else go to login screen which can also take to register if required. Below is the code:

```
if(!login) {
            new Login().execute(username,password);
        } else {
            navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.FirstFragment);
            navController.setGraph(navGraph);
        }
```

As you can see, if login available, i call login task which shall take to home screen after login (yes, it is an api call which i login every time) else i load the login page.

This i am calling from onCreate() method in main activity

My question is
what happens if the loginapi takes longer time, can i delay the activity in loading the fragment?how do i do it?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just wait and only after api call is completed add a fragment that you need. Or, you can always open login screen and make api call automatically if need with some progress bar. Also, you can create additional fragment (let's say AutoLoginFragment) and open it when you need to make login api call.

Comment: yeah but the activity does not wait for me to set destination. It is our setup else it will proceed to load login screen. can i make it wait until loginapi is done?. The same goes for login page as well. I don't want to show the login screen and then show home screen. It has to do it in background.